# Python Packages not installed

Tags: python, spacy

In Python, I was using Spacy library there was trying below commands:-

`import spacy`

Getting Below Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'
```

Then tried to install spacy using below command:-

`pip install spacy`

Message:

It gives Requirement already satisfied.

Commands Used :-

```
import spacy
pip install spacy
```

Comment: There are any number of reasons for this so you'll have to search the many other issues about "I ran pip but got ModuleNotFoundError".  Questions to ask yourself: "did I run the right pip?"  Am I running the same python interpreter that I ran pip with?".  If you want to be certain you can use `python -m pip` instead of just `pip` where replace `python` with whatever python you're using.

Comment: Make sure you are installing into the same python enivronment as you are running python in. Use `python -m pip install spacy; python filename.py` to be sure the python is the same

Comment: run pip install of that module, it will show the 'already satisfied' thing, and it will also show the path in which that module got installed. set that path as an PATH env_variable. Restart system

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install -U spacy` and `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

Answer (score 0):

- Spacy module is a bit more finicky than others
- https://spacy.io/usage <-- use this guide to generate the terminal code to install the correct version.
- This is just an example from the above code generator link.
- You need to generate the installation code that satisfies your own needs.

```
pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
pip install -U spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

In your case becsue you have already installed some version of it I would recommend:

- A.) uninstalling the whole module

  - `pip uninstall spacy`
  - OR
  - [Don't know how to uninstall unwanted Spacy installation, model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53052868/dont-know-how-to-uninstall-unwanted-spacy-installation-model)
- B.) Creating a new fresh environemnt

There are some other libraries that ahev to be adjusted as well.

- So it is important to search more complex frameworks how to install before installing them in a "generalist way".
- Further examples.:

  - https://rapids.ai/start.html
  - https://pytorch.org/